# Postgres JSONB query not finding result even though it exists

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb

I have a `jsonb`-type column called 'payloads' on a table called 'tweets'.

```
SELECT "payload" FROM "tweets";

payload
-------
"{\"id\":\"1596568061574008832\", ...lots more attributes}"
(1 row)
```

BUT

```
SELECT "payload" FROM "tweets" WHERE "payload"->>'id'='1596568061574008832';

payload
-------
(0 rows)
```

I have verified that the column type is indeed `jsonb` by running `\d+ tweets`. Storage on that column is "extended", if that helps.

In addition, I have followed multiple tutorials (I rarely interface with postgres directly, usually through an ORM), such as [this one](http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-postgres-json-data-types.html) and [this one](https://blog.forestadmin.com/how-to-use-jsonb-to-manipulate-json-fields-in-postgresql/), to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/QakYnQ7Y), however it is a little odd that the row is being displayed with `""` and escapes. What are you using to display the row? What *exactly* does `\d+` say about the column?

Comment: @Schwern "What are you using to display the row?" My terminal. "What *exactly* does `\d+` say about the column?" https://imgur.com/a/ddjkcc5

Comment: If you really have those escaped double quotes in your JSON value, then this is a **single** string, not a proper nested JSON value: https://dbfiddle.uk/gcwTQOUm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Was starting to think that. I can see now that this is an issue with my ORM, not really postgres itself. Thanks.

Comment: Solved it. For anyone interested in how this played out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74585976/activerecord-erroneously-escapes-json-string/

Comment: @DennisHackethal Your terminal does not run SQL commands (I hope). I assume you're using `psql`. My suspicions were correct. Glad you got it figured out.