# ActiveRecord erroneously escapes JSON string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `jsonb`-type column called 'payloads' for my `Tweet` model in my Rails 6.1.1 app. I use a [store](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) to access various fields on this attribute directly:

```rb
class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
  store :payload, accessors: [:lang, :text, :entities], coder: JSON
end
```

(Note that the part `coder: JSON` is necessary to change the serialization from the YAML default to JSON – otherwise you end up with YAML in your `jsonb` column.)

When I create a new tweet, I see that ActiveRecord erroneously escapes the JSON string during the insertion:

```rb
Tweet.create payload: {foo: 'bar'}

TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  Tweet Create (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "tweets" ("payload", ...) VALUES ($1, ...) RETURNING "id"  [["payload", "\"{\\\"foo\\\":\\\"bar\\\"}\""], ...]
```

I'm referring to the part `"\"{\\\"foo\\\":\\\"bar\\\"}\""`. It looks like it's been double escaped. This results in a sort of 'stringception' where a string within a string is stored in the `payloads` column, rendering postgres unable to perform any searches on fields using the arrow `->` syntax. Postgres can't recognize this value as JSON. (Seemingly miraculously, however, Rails is able to deserialize the field properly on read operations.)

Another SO user [has illustrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74585530/postgres-jsonb-query-not-finding-result-even-though-it-exists#comment131655391_74585530) the issue here: https://dbfiddle.uk/gcwTQOUm

Comment: While its generally good to share your knowledge by answering your own questions you might want to check for duplicates first. This question has most likely been asked and answered many times already. I'm a bit stumped at searching for a dupe target right know though.

Comment: I did check for duplicates before I posted this, and did so again just now. Not *exhaustively* but I made a reasonable effort. I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70314345/1371131) of yours which mentions the same problem ("double conver[sion]") I ran into, and offers the same solution, but the corresponding question came at it from a different, unrelated angle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I do *not* use `store`, I cannot reproduce the issue:

```rb
Tweet.create payload: {foo: 'bar'}
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Tweet Create (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "tweets" ("payload", ...) VALUES ($1, ...) RETURNING "id"  [["payload", "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"], ...]
```

`"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"` is the desired string.

This has led me to believe that I'm using `store` wrong.

I checked [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html):

> NOTE: If you are using structured database data types (e.g. PostgreSQL `hstore`/`json`, or MySQL 5.7+ `json`) there is no need for the serialization provided by [.store](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods.html#method-i-store). Simply use [.store_accessor](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods.html#method-i-store_accessor) instead to generate the accessor methods. Be aware that these columns use a string keyed hash and do not allow access using a symbol.

In other words, because I was already using a `jsonb`-type column, Rails already knew to serialize the hash – applying another serialization resulted in a double escape.

So, instead of doing:

```rb
store :payload, accessors: [:lang, :text, :entities], coder: JSON
```

I now do:

```rb
store_accessor :payload, :lang, :text, :entities
```

And it works.